# Detect collisions error says I have 9 arguments when I have 8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, collision

It says I have 9 arguments but I only count 8. How do I fix this?

ERROR MESSAGE

```
File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    C:\Python34\2d\main.py  1       
    update  C:\Python34\2d\main.py  53      
TypeError: detectCollisions() takes 8 positional arguments but 9 were given
```

and this is my code

```
import pygame


pygame.init()


screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))

pygame.display.set_caption("use arrows")

class player:

def __init__(self ,x, y):

    self.x = x
    self.y = y
    self.width = 32
    self.height = 32
    self.velocity = 0
    self.falling = False
    self.onGround = False

def detectCollisions(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):

    if (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

        return True

    elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1>=y2):

        return True

    elif (x2+w2>=x1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

        return True

    elif (x2+w2>=x1+w1>=x2 and y2+h2>=y1+h1>=y2):

        return True

    else:

        return False

def update(self, gravity, blockList):
    if (self.velocity < 0):
        self.falling = True

    collision = False
    blockX,blockY =  0,0
    for block in blockList:

        collision = self.detectCollisions(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height, block.x, block.y, block.width, block.height)

        if(collision == True):
            (self.falling == True)
            self.falling == False
            self.onGround== True
            self.velocity = 0

    if(self,onGround == False):
        self.velocity += gravity
    self.y -= self.velocity

def render(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))


class Block:
def __init__ (self, x, y):
   self.x = x
   self.y = y
   self.width = 32
   self.height = 32

def render(self,screen):
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(0,0,0),(self.x, self.y, self.width, self.height))



gravity = -0.5

black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (50,60,200)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

player = player(0,0)

# 25 colums and 19 rows
level1 = [
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
    [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
]

blockList = []

for y in range (0,len(level1)):
    for x in range (0,len(level1[y])):
        if (level1[y][x] == 1):
            blockList.append(Block(x*32, y*32))



gameloop = True
while gameloop:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            gameloop = False


    screen.fill(blue)

    for block in blockList:
        block.render(screen)

    player.update(gravity, blockList)
    player.render(screen)
    clock.tick(60)

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply forgot to include `self` as an argument to the function `detectCollisions`. Just add it as the first argument, as you have done with `update(self, gravity, blockList)` and you'll be fine. The reason for this is that `detectCollisions` is a class method and not a regular function.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python) for more details about the difference between functions and class methods and why you need the *self*.

Comment: can you give me an example because i really dont know what you mean, im sorry ive been up for house making this and im sure tired and need to fix it before i go to bed

Comment: i had self in the decetctCollisions the whole time http://prntscr.com/8nuhkf even look at the code

Comment: I meant when you def'ed `detectCollisions`. So the line `def detectCollisions(x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):` should be changed to `def detectCollisions(self,x1,y1,w1,h1,x2,y2,w2,h2):`